How is Collection<Object> NOT a supertype of all kinds of collections?
I am studying Wildcards from Oracle's documentation, and I can't understand the following section:
*Consider the problem of writing a routine that prints out all the elements in a collection. Here's how you might write it in an older version of the language (that is, a pre-5.0 release):
*
void printCollection(Collection c) {
    Iterator i = c.iterator();
    for (k = 0; k < c.size(); k++) {
        System.out.println(i.next());
    }
}

*And here is a naive attempt at writing it using generics (and the new for loop syntax):
*
void printCollection(Collection<Object> c) {
    for (Object e : c) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

*The problem is that this new version is much less useful than the old one. Whereas the old code could be called with any kind of collection as a parameter, the new code only takes Collection, which, as we've just demonstrated, is not a supertype of all kinds of collections!
*
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html
The tutorial says Collection<Object> is not a supertype of all kinds of collections. I am curious how, for example, ArrayList<String> is not a subtype of Collection<Object>? Also, how is ArrayList<String> not a subtype of ArrayList<Object>?
From my understanding, all classes are descendants of the Object class. Interfaces and primitive types may be an exception.

Collection<Object> has an add(Object) method.

<T> void printCollection(Collection<T> c) { c.stream().forEach(System.out::println); } -- They're talking about Collection<Object> -- you can't pass a List<String> to a method that takes a Collection<Object>. You need a generic method. Such as my example.

Besides the <T> ... Collection<T> construct, I think Collection<?> would also work

From my understanding, all classes are descendants of the Object class.  This is just the way the language is defined.  Generics are not covariant, instead they are invariant.  Thus MyClass<Object> and MyClass<String> are wholly unrelated, they are not subclasses of the other.

@ElliottFrisch Thanks for your comment! Reading your comment, I tried a couple codes and realized how most Collections with parameters that aren't Object can't be initialized for a Collection variable. Do you know why this happens? I thought since ArrayList is a subtype of Collections and String is a subtype of Object, Collections = ArrayList(); should be possible. (but its not)

@markspace That's something new I would have to study about! Thanks a lot!!

See also Covariance, Invariance and Contravariance explained in plain English?

@JuanCNuno Hey thanks! I think the links to these posts sufficiently answer my curiosities. In that case should I delete this post? I'm conflicted because someone put his/her time into writing an answer post to my question

in simple words: a box of oranges is not the same as a box of fruits - apples can be added to second one

@Jinny Welcome! I wouldn't sweat it. If you feel their content is valuable, then leave it up.

Because that's not how the universe works.
Here is some code that is fundamentally problematic:
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Number> numbers = integers;
Number n = 5.5; // a double.
numbers.add(n);
Integer firstInt = integers.get(0);

Go through it. Remember that java is reference based, and there's only one new in that snippet, so there's just the one list. That add call adds that number to the one list. So, you tell me, where should this explode? Because it has to explode somewhere.
If it worked the way you think it should, then I guess it explodes on the last line, where integers.get(0) returns an object of type Double, which isn't an Integer. But that's not really correct - the true asplosion should happen on the add line. Remember, integers and numbers are pointing to the exact same list, so, that is the exact moment where a non-Integer appeared in your List<Integer>, and thus, that line shouldn't be allowed.
But how can the compiler figure out that's the problem line? (and we want this to be a compiler error - that's the whole point of strong explicit type systems - that we catch issues when we write them, not when we run code!)
We have a List<Number> and we call .add() on it, passing an expression of type Number. It is not possible for the compiler to deem that line the problem line.
So, what really happens is the correct call: Generics are invariant, which means, within the <> only the exact type works. a variable of type List<Number> can only have a value assigned to it of a type that is exactly Number inside its <>. Not anything else. Specifically, not subtypes of it: a List<Integer> cannot be assigned to a variable of type List<Number>.
Yes, in 'normal java' (outside of the <>) java is covariant - a subtype is allowed. Number n = someInteger; is fine. List<Number> listOfN = someListOfIntegers; is not fine.
Generics allows you to explicitly opt into co and even contravariance. Here's how that works, with the same snippet:
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<? extends Number> numbers = integers;
Number n = 5.5; // a double.
numbers.add(n);
Integer firstInt = integers.get(0);

Note the ? extends Number which is opting into covariance, and ? is best read as 'I do not know'. As in, you may be tempted to read List<? extends Number> as 'A list that contains things that extend Number' but that is wrong - List<Number> is 'A list that contains things that extend Number' already, then the ? extends would be useless. The right way to read List<? extends Number> is: "A List containing... I do not know. All I know is, whatever type this list contains.. it's either Number or some subtype of Number". And anything you do this has to work for any possible thing it could be.
Hence, now the snippet does fail on the add line. In fact, given a List<? extends Whatever> (and remember that List<?> is just syntax sugar for List<? extends Object>, so that counts to), you cannot add ANYTHING, because to add something, it has to work for any possible choice. So, given that Integer is one thing that fits 'I do not know, all I know is, it's some subtype of Number', and Double is another thing that also fits, what expression is both Integer and Double? None - that's not possible. Except for the academic case of literally list.add(null) (which is the only thing that is allowed here), and that works only because null as an expression is magically all types at the same time.
What you want is printCollection(Collection<?> c).
Which, read it properly: "The parameter takes a Collection of.. I do not know.". But, no matter what choice is made, if you assign thatCollection.get(0) to Object, that's fine - because we do know that collections have to hold objects (they can't hold primitives; they'd be autoboxed into objects). Your code would work for all possible options, and thus, the compiler allows it. You won't be able to call .add on this collection, but that's fine - you aren't calling add. If you tried, the compiler would, correctly, stop you.

Thanks a lot! Your answer was very straightforward :)
